# Adding to dictionary in for loop and progressbar update with two statements

Tags: python, dictionary, progress-bar

In gdic I have 3 keys (1,2,3) and values. In page I have two equals for two keys (1,3). Why to pdic are added only one value? "lol" is printed twice, but it must be printed once, yeah? Progress bar doesn't work correctly for this.

```
    length = len(self._gdic)
    count = 1.0
    count2 = 1
    pbar = ProgressBar().start()

    for k in self.gdic.keys():
        for i in page:
            if (k == i[0].decode('utf-8')): 
                pdic[i[0]] = i[2].lower() 
                percent_done = count / length
                percent_done = round(percent_done * 100)
                pbar.update(percent_done)
                count += 1.0
                count2 = 1
                break
            elif (count2 == length):
                percent_done = count / length
                percent_done = round(percent_done * 100)
                pbar.update(percent_done)
                count += 1.0
                count2 = 1
                print("lol")
                break
            else:
                count2 += 1
                continue
    pbar.finish()
```

**Edit:**  Okay, I probably found the solution.

```
    length = len(page)
    length2 = len(self.gdic)
    count = 1.0
    count2 = 1
    pbar = ProgressBar().start()        
    for k in self.gdic.keys():
        for i in page:
            if (k == i[0].decode('utf-8')): 
                pdic[i[0]] = i[2].lower() 
                percent_done = count / length2
                percent_done = round(percent_done * 100)
                print("ss")
                print k
                pbar.update(percent_done)
                count += 1.0
                count2 = 1
                break
            else:
                if (count2 == length):
                    percent_done = count / length2
                    percent_done = round(percent_done * 100)
                    print("lol")
                    print k
                    pbar.update(percent_done)
                    count += 1.0
                    count2 = 1
                    continue
                count2 += 1
    pbar.finish()
```

### **Description:**

Length of *page (dict)* can be different than length of *gdic (dict)*. If we found *k* in *page*, the progress bar is updating and *count2* is setting to default value. If *k* is not in *page*, we must check *count2* and *length (of page)* values. If they are same, we update the progress bar and set *count2* to default value. If they are not same, we increase *count2*. I am using printing to check working of this solution.

Comment: Well this is hard to read - what is the value of length, for example and what is "two equals for two keys (1,3)"? What is traceback message? I could guess what is happening here, like for example Progressbar() race condition, but since we have no proper error message here, that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Sorry for my english. For example: length is 3 so gdic has 3 pairs (key, value), page length is too 3. Pairs in gdic: {"1": "aa", "2": "bb", "3": "cc"}. In page we found two equal values of keys "if (k == i[0].decode('utf-8')):" (for example: 1 and 3). Key 2 is not in page, so count2 increase. **Error**: ValueError: Value out of range progress bar.

Comment: Sorry, this is still unclear: what is the output of "print (i, str(type(i)))", when placed before Your first if.  What is EXACT key/value pair in "page"? Also, it would be much easier if You edited Your question and pasted full traceback. Otherwise i guess i won't be able to help here.

Comment: @brainovergrow, thanks for the answers. I updated the question with solution which works perfectly.